# Using Solr V2 API to update Solr config in standalone mode throws SolrException "Solr not running in cloud mode"

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solrconfig

Trying to modify config with V2 API in Solr runnning in the standalone mode.

The request is build as follow:

```
V2Request v2Request = new V2Request.Builder(String.format("/collections/%s/config", collectionName))
                                                    .withMethod(SolrRequest.METHOD.POST)
                                                    .withPayload(actionPayLoad)
                                                    .build();
```

That results in the SolrException: "Solr not running in cloud mode "

It appears that V2 Http request is generated through org.apache.solr.apiV2HttpCall(Maven: org.apache.solr:solr-core:7.0.0) which requires to run Zookeeper

```
  protected DocCollection getDocCollection(String collectionName) {
    if (!cores.isZooKeeperAware()) {
      throw new SolrException(SolrException.ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST, "Solr not running in cloud mode ");
    }
```

Is there any equivalent Config API call for Solr running in standalone mode so without Zookeeper?

just noticed from https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/config-api.html that it should work in the similiar fashion:

> The Config API enables manipulating various aspects of your solrconfig.xml using REST-like API > calls.
>   This feature is enabled by default and works similarly in both SolrCloud and standalone mode. > Many commonly edited properties (such as cache sizes and commit settings) and request handler > definitions can be changed with this API.

Comment: You're making a request to `/collections/` - collections is only a term used in cloud mode (which I'm guessing is why its complaining). You want the `/cores/` endpoint, but I'm not sure if the config api is supported for v2 requests for single cores. Are you sure this is supported through the v2 API? The "standard" path would be `/solr/<corename>/config`.

Comment: it appears that it is not possible to use V2 api here. So rewrite the request to V1 SolrRequest. Thx for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution to update solr config through V1 API:

```
Collection<ContentStream> contentStreams = ClientUtils.toContentStreams(actionPayLoad, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                GenericSolrRequest request = new GenericSolrRequest(SolrRequest.METHOD.POST, String.format("/%s/config", collectionName), null);
                request.setContentStreams(contentStreams);
                request.setUseV2(false);
```